# pagerjs - sharing view model with enclosing pages

Tags: knockout.js, pagerjs

If I have something like this with nested pages

```
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'top', withOnShow: topVM}">
  <div data-bind="page: {id: 'sub1', withOnShow: sub1VM}">
    <span data-bind="text:sub1Property"></span>
  </div>
</div>


topVM = function(callback) { callback({topProperty: XXX}); }

sub1VM = function(callback) { 
   // how can I access topVM here?
   callback({sub1Property: XXX}); 
}
```

How can I access the outer page's view model from the inner page's view model?

Answer (score 3):

```
<span data-bind="text:$root.topVMProperty"></span>
```

The link here explains the knockout contexts

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

According to your example you could also do this:

```
<span data-bind="text:$parent[1].topVMProperty"></span>
```

Comment: That would certainly work from the view.  I realized what I was actually after was how to access the outer view model from the inner view model (not from the inner page view bindings) and updated the code example accordingly.

Comment: To do that I have had to either reference my model on my page by having a variable and then have a pass through function on the page or  pass it in as a variable to the model you are using so it can see it.

Comment: `ko.contextFor(document.body)` should return the bound models.